# SSIS EXECUTE TASK not working as expected through sqlserver agent

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, sql-agent

I have created a SSIS Execute Task package to export CSV and write into d:/ drive
It works when i execute from SSIS.However when i run from SQLServer agent, the job shows sucess but the export file is not available in the location
Can anyone please advise if anything i am missing.
Thank you

Comment: you should provide more detail information, like Execution Report, and see which step block and stopped, with this simple information no one can help.

Comment: thanks, not sure how to take execution steps from sql server agent. below is the sucess message when i check in the logs Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.6000.34 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  1:36:41 PM  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).  Started:  1:36:41 PM  Finished: 1:36:41 PM  Elapsed:  0.187 seconds.  The package executed successfully.  The step succeeded.

Comment: if you are use SQL Server 2016+, then click on Integration Service catelogs, and click on your project and right click, they will be a standard report, inside that will be a execution report, sorry I can't remember very clearly about these step, but just try.

Comment: Thanks, i will check

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that the SQL agent doesn't have access to the file system location. Make sure that SQL service account has needed permissions:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)